# CKAN's Data Api search with SQL is not working

Tags: sql, ckan, qsqlquery

CKAN API's are working fine for our data portal but the Data API's with SQL Queries are not working even the base one.

https://data.tn.gov/api/action/datastore_search_sql?sql=SELECT * from "39ea268b-d62e-4f33-a3a2-3d4f9bad82ce"

The base query returns internal server error and with columns and getting all the columns doesn't exist in the table error. Any help is appreciated.